# Processing video frames

Tags: video, video-capture, video-processing, frames

I am trying to find software that perform the following functions:

1. when the compressed frames of a streamed video arrive to a destination server, make a copy of each frame as soon as it arrives at the destination server
2. copy the digitized pixels from a frame to another memory location
3. mix the digitized audio fields of several video frames and copy the result in memory

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't give a detailed impression of what you're trying to achieve or what the constraints are. Could you clarify the question, especially item #3?

FFMPEG would at least solve the problem of outputting the frames (for most formats anyway), and is available on many platforms. See [here](http://stream0.org/2008/02/howto-extract-images-from-a-vi.html) for examples.

e.g.:

```
ffmpeg -i input.dv -r 25 -f image2 images%05d.png
```